# Authentication to JHipster UAA from non-jhipster application

Tags: oauth-2.0, jhipster

I used JHipster to create a micro-service architecture.

I'm using JHipster Registry and JHipster UAA (OAuth2) as authentication solution.

Now I'm looking for a way to authenticate and make some API calls from a mobile application that would be developed outside of JHipster.

I tried to call UAA service from outside by calling /oauth/token ressource but it doesn't work.

Any advices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a microservice architecture, you want to make requests to microservices through the gateway so it can load-balance to your microservices (including the UAA).  Use the login route through the gateway (`/auth/login`), like the Angular and React clients do in [`auth-jwt.service.ts`](https://github.com/ruddell/jhipster-examples/blob/ec17a15c12e9de483baada9a59a42028e70c87c6/src/main/webapp/app/core/auth/auth-jwt.service.ts#L16-L23):

```
login(credentials): Observable<any> {
    const data = {
        username: credentials.username,
        password: credentials.password,
        rememberMe: credentials.rememberMe
    };
    return this.http.post(SERVER_API_URL + 'auth/login', data, {});
}
```

Note that you will also need to handle authentication via cookies, and make sure you sent the XSRF-TOKEN with each request.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: And where should I find this XSRF-TOKEN ?

Comment: In the cookie value.  For example, in React Native: https://github.com/ruddell/ignite-jhipster/blob/62ea68a68a92901e5c66150ce2471f91bf13c556/boilerplate/app/shared/services/api.js.ejs#L27-L34