# What is the correct way to request from a mobile app with password grant type?

Tags: jhipster

Currently I have a mobile app, consuming restful web api (jwt) from a monolithic jhipster backend successfully, now I am porting the monolithic backend to microservices, and there are already registry (jhipster registry v4.0.3), gateway (angular 6), uaa (jhipster UAA) and a microservice generated.

Then I compiled and sent a /auth/login request from postman to gateway, but failed, below is the details of the request:
url: post

```
localhost:8080/auth/login
```

header:

```
Accept: application/json
```

and

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

body as raw:

```
{"username":"admin","password":"admin"}
```

the response is:

```
{
    "error": "access_denied",
    "error_description": "Invalid CSRF Token &#39;null&#39; was found on the request parameter &#39;_csrf&#39; or header &#39;X-XSRF-TOKEN&#39;."
}
```

What is the correct way to request from a mobile app with password grant type? I need oauth 2 (such as refresh token. etc).

Not sure what I missed something, I checked the docs, and did not find something useful.

Feel very appreciated for any help.

Note: the gateway works well (from browser), the gateway, uaa and the microservice are also registered to the registry successfully.

I think it is not a duplicate with other question, because mobile app use token based authentication, the csrf is not necessary in this case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Authentication to JHipster UAA from non-jhipster application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52264350/authentication-to-jhipster-uaa-from-non-jhipster-application)

Comment: Thank you, Jon. I add a "rememberMe" with true, but the error is still there, in my case, there is no cookie and csrf token to be attached to the request. The login dialog is not from the server, but made with android/ios native code.

Comment: The `rememberMe` is not important.  You need to get a cookie with the XSRF token first before you can login (I think you can get one by making a GET request, the webapp requests `/api/account` on page load).  I'm not sure how you handle cookies in native app code though.  Here's how I map the cookie to a request header for React Native, it's not what you're looking for but it might help https://github.com/ruddell/ignite-jhipster/blob/9fb189a6abd97ecaa4789afdf09ab8da15f26146/boilerplate/App/Services/Api.js.ejs#L26-L34

Comment: I think your suggestion should work and I will try. just curious why need cookie and  xsrf in this case. it is not part of oauth 2, right?

Comment: The cookie should be session based, request from mobile should be the token based.

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate question, the mobile app do not need csrf, it should use token based authentication. it may be a jhipster gateway limitation or bug?

Comment: any update on this topic, are you able to log in using any mobile application?

Comment: Creating another dedicated gateway for mobile accessing solved the problem.

Comment: @JamesHao Could you make an answer to your question and provide more a bit more details on the idea (of having a specific gateway for mobile) ?  I'm have exactly the same need and would love to benefit from your experience.  I'm using react-native (with expo), and the mobile app already exists ( not made with jhipster ).  But of course if need be I can change all that.

Comment: @baraber, please see my answer, hope it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Create another gateway for mobile without front-end application like angular or react. please using below command:

```
c:/>jhipster --skip-client
```

choose jhipster registry, uaa, no database, etc

This [link](https://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html) has details for this pattern.

Comment: it will work only if you disable the csrf security from security config class.I also end up by creating seperate gateway for other clients other than web app.